# Vue variable wont work in jquery function

Tags: jquery, laravel, vue.js

i have a little problem that maybe someone of you know how i can solve it.

I want to change the background color dynamically with jquery, the color is saved in database and im getting it with an axios call.

So when i hardcode the background-color it works, but when i give the axios response or the vue variable it doesnt although with console.log() it prints the value ok.

*btw i cant use :style from vue because the div that i want to change its background-color is in a laravel blade file and not in the vue.js component.

```
 getColor() {
        axios.get('/get_kanbans_color/' + this.id).then(res => {
            this.hex_color = res.data.hex
            this.rgba_color = res.data.rgba
            $(function () {
                $("#kanban_board_wrapper").css("background-color", res.data.rgba);
            });
        })
    }
```

[here is a picture of my axios response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XU50i.png)

Comment: `" 'rgba(28, 160, 133,  .7)' "` is not the same as `"rgba(28, 160, 133,  .7)"` , in your case is **string** inside **string**, just change in DB color to be `"rgba(28, 160, 133,  .7)"`

Comment: Hi Vasile, first thanks for you answer, but that's not the problem.
I tried also without the ' ' (apostrophes) and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Your code looks good. First of all - the returned string should be without apostrophes - just a raw string. All I can think of is that you should try to see if your selector - `$("#kanban_board_wrapper")` actually returns a DOM element. Also, maybe you are overwriting the background-color in your CSS somewhere? Is the function to replace the background definitely being called? Try adding a console.log just before you try to change the background.